# How do I set the font size for the axes in the R plot function cdplot()

Tags: r, formatting, plot

I have a simple plot call:

```
cdplot(example~test)
```

I would like to make the font of the axes bigger. However,

```
cdplot(example~test, cex=2.0)
```

does not work, and I cannot find a solution to this. How do I increase the font size?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `par` function to circumvent the problem:

```
#example data from ?cdplot:
fail <- factor(c(2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1,
                 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
               levels = 1:2, labels = c("no", "yes"))
temperature <- c(53, 57, 58, 63, 66, 67, 67, 67, 68, 69, 70, 70,
                 70, 70, 72, 73, 75, 75, 76, 76, 78, 79, 81)

#save old parameters
old.par <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
#change only the size of axis, for axis labels use cex.lab etc, see ?par
par(cex.axis=2)
cdplot(fail ~ temperature)
par(old.par) #restore old parameters
```

From `?cdplot`'s arguments section:

> bw, n, from, to, ... arguments passed to density.

And from `?density`'s arguments section:

> ... further arguments for (non-default) methods.

So you cannot use `cdplot(fail ~ temperature,cex.axis=2)` because the additional parameters "`...`" are used by `density` function which doesn't use them as graphical parameters such as `cex`.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @agstudy of course you are right, `par(cex.axis=2)` will do it for axis tick labels, `par(cex.lab=2)` will do it for axis labels?

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to hack `cdplot` function , to set `cex.axis`.  But I don't encourage hacking function even is here it is a simple function. Myabe better to contact package maintainer to add axis font feature.

Using  `getS3method('cdplot','default')` you get the function source and you change this line as:

```
 Axis(xorig, side = 1,cex.axis=cex.x)
 equidist <- any(diff(y1[, 1L]) < tol.ylab)
 if (equidist) 
    axis(2, at = seq.int(1/(2 * ny), 1 - 1/(2 * ny), 
                           by = 1/ny), labels = yaxlabels, tick = FALSE,cex.axis=cex.y)
 else axis(2, at = (y1[-1L, 1L] + y1[-NROW(y1), 1L])/2, 
              labels = yaxlabels, tick = FALSE,cex.axis=cex.y)
```

I create a new [gist](https://gist.github.com/agstudy/24c74b0b8a4c38564c33) with the new function.

For example:

```
my.cdplot(y=fail ,x=temperature,cex.x=2,cex.y=3)
```

[image]